# timedelta not working with isoformat time python

Tags: python, datetime

I am working with UTC time format as: **2019-04-30T18:34:34.297846**
I have to calculate the timestamp with timedelta of 30 minutes:
I have solved as:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

delta = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=29)
final = str(delta)[:10]+'T'+str(delta)[11:]
print(final)
```

I am wondering if it can be solved as:

```
delta = datetime.utcnow().isoformat() - timedelta(minutes=29)
```

But its not working. Looking if there is any alternatives.

Comment: `isoformat()` returns a `str`, not a `datetime`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

delta = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=30)
print(delta.isoformat())

# 2019-04-30T18:53:50.676939
```

Comment: On a more general note, you can have a look at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: You could consolidate this to `(datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=29)).isoformat()` if you really just want the iso string output with no further need for the datetime object.